Create & Send EmailMessage through REST API
I am using the REST API to create an EmailMessage related to a Case. My goal is for this Email to be sent to the customer as if it was sent by a rep directly from the Salesforce UI, with all of the normal Email2Case benefits associated (Email Thread Id, etc).
Here is my REST request:
{
    "Incoming":false,
    "HtmlBody": "test22",
    "FromAddress":"morgansFakeEmail@NotMyAddress.com",
    "FromName":"Morgan",
    "Subject":"Test Email22",
    "TextBody":"TextTest22",
    "ToAddress":"ethansFakeEmail@NotMyAddress.com",
    "ParentId":"5004z00001uFGaCAAW",
    "RelatedToId":"5004z00001uFGaCAAW"
}

The EmailMessage is created successfully, and shows up in the UI related to the Case. Opening the email and looking at the Details shows the Status is Sent, but no email was ever received. Deliverability is set to All Email.
How can I send an EmailMessage from a Case to a customer via the API? I found some SOAP Documentation for SendEmailMessage() but it expects a Draft email, and my emails are not Draft. Attempting to create the EmailMessage in Draft format directly from the API results in an error:
[
    {
        "message": "operation is not allowed",
        "errorCode": "INVALID_OPERATION",
        "fields": []
    }
]


Did you find a solution by any chance?

@artshoque nope, unfortunately not. From what I can tell, it seems like it may not be supported to send Email2Case emails through the API. Not sure if this is intentional, or just not well documented - but all I've been able to figure out so far is that I can create a custom REST Endpoint and build my own custom feature to send SingleEmail messages related to the Case - but there are significant org limits to this feature. Maybe they don't want people using a third-party tool to manage Service? At the moment we've given up on this requirement.
